# Geometric viewpoint on $\Bbbk[t]\to \Bbbk(t)$ not being of finite type

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field and consider the obvious injection $\Bbbk[t]\to \Bbbk(t)$. It seems intuitively obvious this is not a finitely generated $\Bbbk[t]$-algebra, so as a commutative ring morphism it is not of finite type.

Moving over to the geometry it seems being of finite type asserts the existence of a bundle arrow $$\begin{smallmatrix} \mathrm{Spec\;}\Bbbk (t) \\ \downarrow  \\ \mathbb A_\Bbbk^1 \end{smallmatrix} \to \begin{smallmatrix} \mathbb A_{\Bbbk [t]}^n \\ \downarrow \\ \mathbb A_\Bbbk^1 \end{smallmatrix}\cong \begin{smallmatrix} \mathbb A_\Bbbk^{n+1} \\ \downarrow \\ \mathbb A_\Bbbk^1 \end{smallmatrix}$$ for some natural $n$. The injection $\Bbbk[t]\to \Bbbk(t)$ seems to correspond to the generic point of the affine line.

What's the geometry here? Why can't there be such a bundle arrow for a natural $n$, and on the other hand why is there always a bundle arrow when $n$ is possibly infinite?

Comment: Being of finite type would mean that there exists *a closed immersion* $\operatorname{Spec}k(t)\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^n_{k[t]}$ (not just any morphism) over $k[t]$. But there isn't... I don't have much intuition on the topology and geometry of the affine space of infinite dimension. I'll leave that to someone else (but I suspect the only thing we can say is : there exists such a morphism because looking at the corresponding commutative rings, we can find a morphism of rings)

Comment: @Roland why is there no such closed immersion? (Regarding the infinite case I remain hopeful for at least a hint of geometry.)

Comment: In the finite case as well as the infinite case, the answer would be : because at the level of function rings, there is no surjection $k[t,x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow k(t)$ but there is a surjection $k[t,x_1,x_2,...]\rightarrow k(t)$. I know that this is not what you are looking for, but this is how it is done unfortunately...

Comment: Since closed immersions are stable under base change, we may assume that $\Bbb k$ is algebraically closed. In this case, all reduced closed one-point subschemes of $\Bbb A^n_{\Bbb{k}[t]}\cong \Bbb A^{n+1}_{\Bbb k} $ are isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb{k}$ by the Nullstellensatz. Not sure if that's properly "geometric".